# How to draw arc on sphere with three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, geometry, three.js

I have some troubles to draw arc on a sphere between 2 points.
My approach is :

- draw an arc of angle between P1 and P2 with the sphere radius and starting to 0
- rotate around the X axis
- rotate around the Z axis
- rotate around the Y axis

My function is :

```
// compute angle between p1 and p2
var angle = Math.acos(p1.dot(p2)/(p1.length()*p2.length()));
// create arc
var geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(earthRadius, earthBands, 0, angle);
// remove center vertex
geometry.vertices.splice(0,1);
// rotate around x axis
geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(Math.atan((p2.z-p1.z) / (p2.y-p1.y))));
// rotate around z axis
geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(-Math.atan(p1.y / p1.x)));
// rotate around y axis
geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(Math.atan(p1.z / p1.y)));
```

Is it a good way to draw arc on sphere?
Why arcs are not rotated correctly?

Comment: look here for the right equations http://stackoverflow.com/a/22089623/2521214 for sphere mapping. btw what is your output now (what is wrong with it)? image will be best ...

Comment: If you use the angle formula frequently, you could use the THREE.Vector3 method, i.e.: `var angle = p1.angleTo(p2)`.